# I got an error while building gradle in android studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
>       File1: C:\Users\Balamasthan G.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Balamasthan G.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar

Answer (score 7):

you might need to add this to your gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

    }
```

Comment: Include packagingOptions inside android{} exposure or use android.packagingOptions in case of not being found.

Answer (score 1):

in your app gradle file use multidex:enabled

```
android {
      compileSdkVersion 22
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

      defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 }
```